# Why this code doesn't build with clang, crashes with gcc, but runs fine with VC++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, gcc, clang

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main()
{
    std::async([]{std::cout << "hello\n";}).get();
}
```

runs fine and prints `hello` with Visual C++ 2013, but throws an exception with gcc producing:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  Unknown error -1
```

and doesn't even build with clang, producing this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/source-83f28e.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_setspecific@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I used [rexter](http://rextester.com/runcode) to run the tests. Can you explain this behavior?

**EDIT**

With `-pthread` compiler option gcc version runs fine and clang version builds now and produces:

```
hello
exception_ptr not yet implemented
```

Comment: Have you used the `-pthread` flag?

Comment: This isn't really a "crash".

Comment: @juanchopanza _marked as duplicate_ this is correct, especially with help of hindsight. Clang error message leads to linker options, but gcc message - not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order you add support for multithreading, you need to link against the pthread library. This is `-pthread` (available as a built-in flag) on both GCC and Clang. Alternatively, `-lpthread` may do the trick.